# How to not build Android project in workspace?

Tags: android, eclipse, build, workspace

I'm using Eclipse for Android development. Lets say I have a project A that uses code from project B. 
In project A: I setup a link to a sourcefolder to code i project B.

The linked code will build, but some other code in B has errors. Can I have project B included i my workspace but exclude it from the auto-build-process?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either you have to move the needed code from project B to your project A or otherwise you **must** fix errors in project B.

Comment: Okay, thank you! So it's impossible to exclude a project from the build?!

Answer (score 0):

> **The linked code will build, but some other code in B has errors.**
>
> --> AFAIK if you have error in any of line inside your Project B then you
> will have to solve out that errors first. though you are nothing to do
> as you have said its not linked code you want to Use inside your
> Project A. but you will have to solve out the All Errors inside
> Project B. then an only then you will get Use those Code From Project
> B.

`Alternative:` if you have only some of line of code that you want to Use inside Project A. then you can also Write that code inside Project A. No need to make reference of Project B.

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Thank you, but I'm afraid it doesnt solve my problem. Project B does not build because of missing dependencies. The reason that I still want it in my workspace is to make it obvious that my solusion depends on it.